# Is this ClassCastException a HtmlUnit bug?

Tags: htmlunit

I'm new to htmlunit (2.23) and I can't get this test to work:
I'm getting this ClassCastException thrown out of HtmlUnit and I don't know if it is a bug, or if I am doing something wrong.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.TextPage cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.makeWebResponseForJavaScriptUrl(WebClient.java:1241)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:375)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:304)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:451)
>       at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:436)
>       at org.wyttenbach.dale.mlec.OutageTest.test(OutageTest.java:46)
>   ...

The code

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.JavaScriptPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.TextPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class OutageTest {

  private static final String SITE_URL = "https://ebill.mlecmn.net/woViewer/";

  private static final String OUTAGE_MAP_URL = SITE_URL + "mapviewer.html?config=Outage+Web+Map";

  @Test
  public void test() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
      webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);
      webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
      webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
      Map<String, Page> urls = new HashMap<String, Page>();
      LinkedList<String> urlsToVisit = new LinkedList<String>();
      urlsToVisit.add(OUTAGE_MAP_URL);
      while (!urlsToVisit.isEmpty()) {
        String url = urlsToVisit.remove();
        if (urls.containsKey(url)) {
          continue;
        }
        Page page = webClient.getPage(url);
        urls.put(url, page);
        if (page instanceof HtmlPage) {
          HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) page;
          System.err.println("================================================================");
          System.err.println(page2.asXml());
          System.err.println("================================================================");
          Assert.assertFalse("Outage in Nordland township: " + url, page2.asText().contains("Nordland"));
          urlsToVisit.addAll(extractLinks(page2));
        } else if (page instanceof JavaScriptPage) {
          JavaScriptPage page2 = (JavaScriptPage) page;  
          Assert.assertFalse("Outage in Nordland township: " + url, page2.getContent().contains("Nordland"));
        } else if (page instanceof TextPage) {
          TextPage page2 = (TextPage) page;  
          Assert.assertFalse("Outage in Nordland township: " + url, page2.getContent().contains("Nordland"));
        } else {
          System.err.println(String.format("%s => %s", url, page.getClass().getName()));
        }
      }
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
      reportOutage();
      throw e;
    }
  }

  private Collection<String> extractLinks(HtmlPage page) {
    List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (DomElement x : page.getElementsByTagName("script")) {
      String src = x.getAttribute("src");
      if (!src.contains(":")) {
        src = SITE_URL + src;
        System.err.println("script src="+src);
      }
      links.add(src);
    }
    for (DomElement x : page.getElementsByTagName("link")) {
      String href = x.getAttribute("href");
      if (!href.contains(":")) {
        href = SITE_URL + href;
        System.err.println("link href="+href);
      }
      links.add(href);
    }
    // Causes ClassCastException com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.TextPage cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
    //at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.makeWebResponseForJavaScriptUrl(WebClient.java:1241)
    for (DomElement x : page.getElementsByTagName("iframe")) {
      String src = x.getAttribute("src");
      if (!src.contains(":")) {
        src = SITE_URL + src;
        System.err.println("iframe src="+src);
      }
      links.add(src);
    }
    return links;
  }

  private void reportOutage()  {
    try {
      Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(OUTAGE_MAP_URL));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Huh?  Well of course your code is not working if you have an exception.  Please clarify.

Comment: Consider creating a [_Minimal_, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The intention is that the test should fail if it finds the word "Nordland" anywhere in the web page or its linked pages...But I don't know enough about how htmlunit to know how to properly implement extractLinks method, or if this is even going to be possible.  And I'm fairly certain I'm not exhaustively searching through all the links yet, and the exception is one barrier to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less yes - but i have to do a more deeper analysis.
But there is some hope for you ;-)

Your code tries to extract urls from a given web page. During the process you are adding the url 'javascript:""' to your list of urls to be processes. This url results in this class cast exception. If you do not add this url to the list, the test is working (at least for me).